# some solution needed for controlling screen resolution and depth [WinXP Embedded]

Tags: .net, winapi, windows-xp, device

I've got a program which requires a 1280x768 32 bit display, but the computer on which it runs is ultimately going to be headless.

Why does resolution and depth matter on a headless computer?  The program actually identifies and responds to certain changes that take place on the display device, but those changes happen to be immaterial to the user - just the responses matter.

Yes, there's a lot wrong.  I'll take any way that will make this work ('working' requires that the entire display gets updated as expected - no strange black boxes), no matter how dirty.  Tricks with remote desktop, fake drivers, injecting fake devices using win32, 'breaking' whatever monitor windows thinks is attached and forcing a screen resolution change.  Whatever works.

Comment: I should add that the display driver is an Intel 855 Embedded.  These system specs aren't going to change on the devices where this program will be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can force a screen resolution change by using remote desktop.