# Launch app via remote desktop

Tags: execution, interactive, rdp, psexec

Related to this

[some solution needed for controlling screen resolution and depth [WinXP Embedded]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267601/some-solution-needed-for-controlling-screen-resolution-and-depth-winxp-embedded/6279342#6279342)

I need to remotely launch a program.  Previously this worked great via psexec, but whenever remote desktop has run/is running I get:

> psexec \ip -u admin -p pass -i cmd /C "commands..."
>   No process on the other end of the pipe

execcmd doesn't work either.  Alternatives?  I can't be guaranteed that any software or service will be available on the remote machine.